# discord.py wait and analyze input using imported file

Tags: python, pandas, discord.py

I'm making a bot that takes in the user input (which is a stock symbol) and then provides information on that specific stock. Thing is, I'm not really sure how to use the `client.wait_input()` in my case. Here's my code for the bot:

```py
# bot.py
import os
import SandPwebscraper as stocks
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')

@bot.command(name = 'symbol', help = 'Type in all-caps symbol of company (ex. when searching for Apple, type AAPL).')
async def Symbol(ctx, companySymbol: str):
    #
    #
    #
    # 
    # 
    # 
    await ctx.send(''.join)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

And I'm trying to somehow include the `stocks_input()` function from `SandPwebscraper.py`:

```py
# Web-scraped S&P 500 data for 500+ US stocks.

import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36 Edg/96.0.1054.62'}

url = 'https://www.slickcharts.com/sp500' # Data from SlickCharts
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

table1 = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'table table-hover table-borderless table-sm'})

for row in table1.find_all('tr'):
    all_td_tags = row.find_all('td')
    if len(all_td_tags) > 0:
        company = all_td_tags[1].text
        symbol = all_td_tags[2].text
        weight = all_td_tags[3].text
        price = all_td_tags[4].text
        chg = all_td_tags[5].text
        perChg = all_td_tags[6].text
        # print(company, '|', symbol, '|', weight, '|', price, '|', chg, '|', perChg)

df = pd.read_html(str(table1))[0]   # Makes data into an html readable and can output and look through data
df.drop(['#'], axis = 1, inplace = True)    # Removes an extra column of numbers
# pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)     # Removes cap on number of rows in viewall

def viewall():
    allStocks = df
    return allStocks

def appletest():
    apple = df[df['Symbol'] == 'AAPL']
    return apple

def stocks_input():
    userinput = input('Enter company name or symbol: ')

    if userinput.isupper():
        symbol = (df[df['Symbol'] == userinput])
        return symbol
    else:
        if userinput == 'viewall':
            allStocks = df
            return allStocks
        else:
            company = (df[df['Company'] == userinput])
            return company
```

In this case, if `userinput` is something like "AAPL", then the following would be returned:

```
      Company Symbol    Weight   Price   Chg     % Chg
0  Apple Inc.   AAPL  6.888732  177.65 -1.73  (-0.96%)
```

What should I include in the commented section of `bot.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `companySymbol` variable already stores the user's input, so you can modify the `stocks_input()` function to take input.

```py
def stocks_input(userinput):
    if userinput.isupper():
        symbol = (df[df['Symbol'] == userinput])
        return symbol
    else:
        if userinput == 'viewall':
            allStocks = df
            return allStocks
        else:
            company = (df[df['Company'] == userinput])
            return company
```

Now you can run this function with the `companySymbol` as an input:

```py
@bot.command(name = 'symbol', help = 'Type in all-caps symbol of company (ex. when searching for Apple, type AAPL).')
async def Symbol(ctx, companySymbol: str):
    values = stocks.stocks_input(companySymbol) # stocks_input function will return values and store it in 'values' variable

    await ctx.send(values) # send values
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! When I try to test out the program using `$symbol AAPL`, I get this following error:
`raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`
I'm not really sure what that error means. I also included the code for `SandPwebscraper.py` in the original post in case that helps.

Comment: I edited my answer. I included only the `stocks_input` function because you have to change only this one in `SandPwebscraper.py` and also a small change in `bot.py`. The rest should stay the same. Everything should work, I tested it, but if you have any problems let me know :D

Comment: Yep that seems to work! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to help! :) Btw. I think that it might look pretty cool as an [embed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed). If you want you might want to play with it a little bit.